# Find words that can be typed using only one row on a keyboard

Tags: c++, programming-challenge

on leetcode.com, there is a question with the following description:

> Given a List of words, return the words that can be typed using letters of alphabet on only one row's of American keyboard like the image below.
>   [link to the question here.](https://leetcode.com/problems/keyboard-row/description/)

Here is my implementation:

```
class Solution {
public:
    std::vector<std::string> findWords(std::vector<std::string>& words) 
    {
        std::unordered_set<char> firstRow = {'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'P'};
        std::unordered_set<char> secondRow = {'A','S','D','F','G','H','J','K','L'};
        std::unordered_set<char> thirdRow = {'Z','X','C','V','B','N','M'};
        std::vector<std::string> result;

        size_t vecSize = words.size();
        for(size_t i = 0; i < vecSize; ++i)
        {
                if(sameRow(words[i], firstRow))
                    result.push_back(words[i]);
                else if(sameRow(words[i], secondRow))
                    result.push_back(words[i]);
                else if(sameRow(words[i], thirdRow))
                    result.push_back(words[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
    bool sameRow(const std::string& words, const std::unordered_set<char>& row)
    {
                size_t wordSize = words.size();
                for(size_t j = 0; j < wordSize; ++j)
                {
                    if(row.find(toupper(words[j])) == row.end())
                    {
                       return false;
                    }
                }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: if you're allowed to use C `strspn()` was made for this!

Comment: In C++, `std::strspn()` is the same function, @Jasen!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Algorithm/Data Structure Selection

Right now you're using three separate sets, one of the letters in each row of the keyboard.

Instead, I think I'd use a single map from character to row number. Then you can start with the first character in the string, and find what row it's on. Then you check whether the other characters in the word are in the same row. Right now, you may look up each character in a string up to three separate times. Changing the algorithm, you can reduce that to (at most) one lookup per character.

Since you have a dense set of inputs for the map (i.e., only ASCII letters) I'd probably also use an array/vector for the mapping, instead of an unordered map. A vector/array will avoid hashing, and it's a dense structure, so you get really good cache utilization.

#### Avoid Unnecessary Transformations

It's probably simpler to create a mapping for all possible input characters instead of using `toupper` on the input, then looking it up in the set/map.

#### Consider other Looping Constructs

Instead of a loop like this:

```
            size_t wordSize = words.size();
            for(size_t j = 0; j < wordSize; ++j)
            {
                if(row.find(toupper(words[j])) == row.end())
                {
                   return false;
                }
            }
```

I'd probably use a loop more like this:

```
for (auto c : words[j] )
    if (row.find(c) == row.end())
        return false;
return true;
```

...or you could use a standard algorithm instead:

```
return std::all_of(words[j].begin(), words[j].end(), 
    [&](char c) { return row.find(c) != row.end(); });
```

(Though, as outlined above, I'd rather change it to look up the row number instead).

Answer (score 4):

This is mostly implementation of what @Jerry said in his answer.

### Separation of concerns

It's nice that you extracted most of the predicate logic out of the loop. After doing so, it is useful to check list of range algorithms of standard library, in case there is one that fits the bill.

### Alternatives

Aside from what @Jerry mentioned, there is a possibility to use `std::copy_if` along with `std::back_inserter`. Using `std::string_view` inside a predicate might also be an improvement if used as standalone in the future (probably it won't).

### Constructing table

I'd use a scripting language to generate the table or maybe load it from file. Problems like this are somewhat annoying by not providing the tables.

### Putting it together

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string_view>
#include <cctype>

class row_allocation{
    std::array<char, 256> letter_locations;
public:
    row_allocation() {
        letter_locations['Q'] = 0;
        letter_locations['W'] = 0;
        letter_locations['E'] = 0;
        letter_locations['R'] = 0;
        letter_locations['T'] = 0;
        letter_locations['Y'] = 0;
        letter_locations['U'] = 0;
        letter_locations['I'] = 0;
        letter_locations['O'] = 0;
        letter_locations['P'] = 0;
        letter_locations['A'] = 1;
        letter_locations['S'] = 1;
        letter_locations['D'] = 1;
        letter_locations['F'] = 1;
        letter_locations['G'] = 1;
        letter_locations['H'] = 1;
        letter_locations['J'] = 1;
        letter_locations['K'] = 1;
        letter_locations['L'] = 1;
        letter_locations['Z'] = 2;
        letter_locations['X'] = 2;
        letter_locations['C'] = 2;
        letter_locations['V'] = 2;
        letter_locations['B'] = 2;
        letter_locations['N'] = 2;
        letter_locations['M'] = 2;
    }

    int operator[](char letter) {
        auto normalized_letter = std::toupper(letter);
        return letter_locations[normalized_letter];
    }
};

auto is_one_row = [](std::string_view word) {
    static row_allocation allocation;
    if (word.empty())
        return true;
    auto first_letter_row = allocation[word.front()];
    return std::all_of(std::next(word.begin()), word.end(), 
                       [first_letter_row](char letter) {
                           return allocation[letter] == first_letter_row;
                       });
};

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::copy_if(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin), {},
                 std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "),
                 is_one_row);
}
```

---

There is a possibility for `constexpr`, but I guess it is not worth the effort for such a small problem.

It is better to initialize all elements of `letter_locations` and just directly map to it. I didn't initialize them all here due to my laziness and brevity.

Comment: When constructing the table (which isn't zero-initialized), would it be better to map all characters to its integer value, then map row characters to a character in its own group? If you are going to hold all 256 characters, you may as well drop the upper conversion and map the lowercase characters.

Comment: @Snowhawk, you're totally right. I was just lazy and thought that gigantic initialization will obfuscate the point. I'll leave a note about it at the bottom, thanks. I've got an internship lately and am buried under my to-do list, as the technology is quite new to me. I might get into low profile soon. Actually you can edit it into the answer, as it is community wiki. I didn't want to get the rep, as it is mostly an implementation.